# Cloud Build passing args to an entrypoint with exec

Tags: docker, exec, google-cloud-build

I have a Dockerfile with the following `ENTRYPOINT` command that uses exec.

```
FROM node:10-alpine
RUN apk add ca-certificates
RUN npm install -g firebase-tools

COPY --from=gcr.io/berglas/berglas:latest /bin/berglas /bin/berglas

ENV FIREBASE_TOKEN ""

ENTRYPOINT exec /bin/berglas exec -- /usr/local/bin/firebase
```

In `cloudbuild.yaml` I have the following step but the arguments passed in `args: []` are not being respected.

```yaml
  - name: firebase-tools
    dir: '/workspace/functions'
    args: ['deploy', '-P', '${_FIREBASE_PROJECT_NAME}']
    env:
      - 'FIREBASE_TOKEN=sm://$PROJECT_ID/firebase-ci-token'
```

Because `exec` changes the shell it ignores the original `args: []`. Is there a means of applying these `args: []` for the `/usr/local/bin/firebase deploy` command?

Comment: could  you please explain more of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Of course. `berglas` is pulling secrets from Google Secret manager and this is being made available in the container environment as `FIREBASE_TOKEN`. After `berglas` has done it's job, I want to then call `/usr/local/bin/firebase` with the dynamic args passed in from the cloudbuild.yaml file `[ 'deploy', '-P', '${_FIREBASE_PROJECT_NAME} ]`. The args just appear to be ignored by the container though. I've made the assumption that this is because of exec destroy the shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your actual problem is that you're using the string from of `ENTRYPOINT`.  This wraps the command string in `sh -c '...'`, which will ignore any additional arguments passed as the command part.  **`ENTRYPOINT` must use JSON-array syntax to take additional parameters in `CMD`.**

```sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/berglas", "exec", "--", "/usr/local/bin/firebase"]
```

Since this form doesn't have a shell wrapper (it just runs the command directly) you don't need the outer `exec` here.

(I'd consider rearranging this so that you have `CMD ["firebase"]`, and the `ENTRYPOINT` line ends in the `--` delimiter.  Then `CMD` is a complete command and you can easily do things like run debugging shells inside the environment wrapper.)

Comment: That works, thanks. so based on your consideration, does the bottom of the docker file then look like `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/berglas", "exec", "--"] \n CMD ["firebase"]`?

Comment: Exactly.  Those get combined together into a single command line.